# jquery: addClass 1,2,3 etc. auto to a list

Tags: jquery, list, addclass

is it possible, to add auto numeric classes to a list by using jquery?

html:

```
<ul id="list">
 <li>Element 1</li>
 <li>Element 2</li>
 <li>Element 3</li>
 <li>Element 4</li>
 <li>Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

i want to get something like this:

```
<ul id="list">
 <li class="1">Element 1</li>
 <li class="2">Element 2</li>
 <li class="3">Element 3</li>
 <li class="4">Element 4</li>
 <li class="5">Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

hope there is a solution available :-)

---

### Edit

ok, mhhm but my list has not always a number at the end. so what's about a classname combination, like "item + number" ? is something like this possible?

```
<ul id="list">
 <li class="item1">Element x</li>
 <li class="item2">Element c</li>
 <li class="item3">Element a</li>
 <li class="item4">Element d</li>
 <li class="item5">Element f</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you should add classes before page renders inside for loop

Answer (score 20):

```
   $("#list li").each(function(i) {
     this.addClass("item"+(i+1));
    });
```

Here it is in action

http://jsbin.com/ocake

Update per comments, as in example link this works :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#list li").each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass("item" + (i+1));
        });
      });
```

But I think initial code should work by adding :

```
this = $(this);
```

But not sure.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#list").children().each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("prefix_" + (i+1));
});
```

Comment: +1, simplest solution and doesn't require string parsing. Small fix: should be `this.addClass(i+1)`.

Comment: This is assuming you want to add the class based on the elements position, as opposed to the text contained inside it (which everyone else seems to have assumed..)

Comment: thanks :-), but that function does not work, also the i+1 fix doesn't   :-??

Comment: no, it does not :?? but firebug reports no problems.. strange

Comment: tested the above code on my pc - it definitely works - make sure your <ul> has the id of "list"

Comment: This is overkill. For this specific purpose, `$("#list li")` is far better than `$("#list").children()`.

Comment: Care to explain why it's far better?

Answer (score 2):

CSS 2 has some special rules relating to numeric class names. See the [grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html), specifically "class" within G.1, "nmstart" in G.2, and the final bullet point in G.3.

Using classes .c1 through .c5:

```
$('#list li').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass( 'c' + $(this).text().substr(-1) );
});
```

Note that this assumes the very last character of the `<li>` is a number. You may have to tweak (possibly using regex) for your exact use case.

Comment: I think numbers are allowed - see the last line in your link.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing it out. This was a case where years ago I hit a browser that didn't support numeric classes, so I stopped using them, then this post prompted me to find out the "why" :)

Comment: @macek I know, I already pointed that out in my answer. Ostensibly this is a site for programmers, who I hope would have some ability to adapt what they are learning within this site.

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery 1.4.x:

```
$("#list > li").addClass(function(i){return "item" + (i + 1);});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#list li').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass( $(this).text().split(' ')[1] );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, mhhm but my list has not always a number at the end. so what's about a classname combination, like "item + number" ? is something like this possible?

```
<ul id="list">
 <li class="item1">Element x</li>
 <li class="item2">Element c</li>
 <li class="item3">Element a</li>
 <li class="item4">Element d</li>
 <li class="item5">Element f</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If your question has changed, you should delete this answer and instead rewrite the question.

Comment: @Adam Backstrom, I cleaned this up for him.